# Is it possible to conditionally render only the placeholder attribute in a input tag in React?

Tags: reactjs, conditional-rendering

I want to do something like the following:

```
        return (
          <input  
            {(tagsArrayEmpty) ? placeholder='enter your tags' : placeholder='empty'}
            type="text"
          />
        )
```

but I get the error: Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "..."

Is it possible to conditionally render just the placeholder portion of the input tag rather than the full input tag? I read the documentation for [conditional rendering here](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) but all the examples only render full tags at a minimum. Just wondering if there is a way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, like this:

```js
       return (
          <input  
            placeholder={tagsArrayEmpty ? 'enter your tags' : 'empty'}
            type="text"
          />
        )
```

Comment: what if i want to have search icon from fontawesome in placeholder like this '&#xF002;'?

Comment: That probably deserves its own question